# How to output a class method as an attribute in Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I am currently using the following jbuilder code to output all attributes of each of the @ods

```
json.ods @ods do |od|
  json.od od
end
```

I want to add the result of a class method to output as an additional attribute.  Is this possible without having to list each and every attribute individually?

Thanks

Comment: class method of od?

Comment: `json.od od` - this presumably calls a jbuilder view for this od. Let's see that.

Comment: {
ods: [
{
od: {
id: 300,
sophead_id: 126,
created_at: "2018-03-27T14:46:41.789Z",
updated_at: "2018-03-27T15:52:29.935Z",
status: "Open",
del_postcode: " ",
route_name: "Call & Collect - 10",
route_id: 23,
est_pick_pack_time: 180,
due_date_time: "2018-03-26T22:57:00.000Z"
}
},
{
od: {
id: 314,
sophead_id: 493,
created_at: "2018-03-27T14:46:43.600Z",
updated_at: "2018-03-27T15:52:31.226Z",
status: "Open",
del_postcode: " ",
route_name: " - 17",
route_id: null,
est_pick_pack_time: 120,
due_date_time: "2018-03-26T22:58:00.000Z"
}
},...etc for each od

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call class method

```
json.method ClassName.method_name
json.ods @ods do |od|
  json.od od
end
```

or for instance method

```
json.ods @ods do |od|
  json.od od
  json.method od.method
end
```

to merge with the instance attributes

```
json.ods @ods do |od|
  json.od od.attributes.merge(method: od.method)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, when doing

json.ods sorted_ods do |od|
  json.od od
  json.test od.test
end

It returns the result of .test correctly 
ods: [
{
od: {
id: 314,
sophead_id: 493,
...etc
},
test: 1
},

But I want to merge this with the other attributes of od, but trying:

json.ods sorted_ods do |od|
  json.od od.merge(od_test: od.test)
end

returns undefined method `merge' for od

Comment: you can merge by using attributes like this `od.attributes.merge(od_test: od.test)`, but remember returned json will be a hash in that case and not an object

Comment: Thanks, this worked:

json.ods sorted_ods do |od|
  json.od od.attributes.merge(od_test: od.test)
end

Comment: @daveanderson88 I've updated the answer please accept it for the sake of others convenience.